# Database owner unable to create tables under Postgres 15 (RDS)

Tags: postgresql, amazon-rds, postgresql-15

I realise a change was introduced relating to default permissions in Postgres 15: https://www.postgresql.org/about/news/postgresql-15-released-2526/, specifically

> PostgreSQL 15 also revokes the CREATE permission from all users except a database owner from the public (or default) schema.

However, I'm a bit lost as to why I'm unable to create a table as the database *owner*. See below.

```
psql postgres://my_user:my_pass@my_host/postgres -c 'create database my_db'

      datname      |  datdba  | is_owner
-------------------+----------+----------
       my_db       |  my_user | t

#The line below doesn't seem to have succeeded, presumably because it's mostly CREATE TABLE ...
psql postgres://my_user:my_pass@my_host/my_db < my_default_dump.sql

psql -h my_host -p 5432 -U my_user -d my_db

my_db=> create table test (a int);
ERROR:  permission denied for schema public
```

This could be relevant at bottom of SQL dump referenced earlier, but there's no reference to my_user:

```
REVOKE ALL ON SCHEMA public FROM PUBLIC;
REVOKE ALL ON SCHEMA public FROM postgres;
GRANT ALL ON SCHEMA public TO postgres;
GRANT ALL ON SCHEMA public TO PUBLIC;
```

This database is hosted by AWS RDS.

"My_user" is not the super user. I can access the super user's credentials if need be (infrastructure provided by external partner), but needing them isn't ideal as the process dynamically creating this database is existing and we don't want to introduce additional code (and certainly not super user credentials) if at all possible.

This process works with Postgres 9.6, hosted locally.